# ASP Classic : Put a "variable" in a "Request.Form()"

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a form that will send an array of data to an ASP page.
Let's say this array is called "matrix".

Usually, on the ASP receiving the form, I will write this out to retrieve the form inputs from the array "matrix".

```
Request.Form("matrix[]")(i)  where i = 1, 2, 3 which are the elements in the array.
```

Let's say I want to do make a variable like this

```
a="matrix"
```

and I want to use this variable `a` and put it into the request form, instead of writing `"matrix"`, so that it would look something like this

```
Request.Form(a[])(i)
```

How can it be done? For now, all my attempts are showing blank. e.g. when I try to make them appear on the page with response.write, nothing shows up.

Please help me or let me know if it cannot be done, I've been spending hours on this.

Comment: `Request.Form()` takes a `string` key as the identifier so any valid string variable will work passed to `Request.Form(mystringvariable)`. I'm struggling to follow what you are trying to do. If you want to pass an Array first define it `Array("matrix", "something", "else")` then pass the element you want to `Request.Form()`, something like `Request.Form(thearray(0))` is eqivalent to `Request.Form("matrix")`.

Comment: @Lankymart thanks lankymart your reply helped me understand Request.Form better. I've tested it and it works!

Comment: Like Lankymart, I'm puzzled about what you're trying to do. Are you somehow under the impression that square brackets will magically make things into an array? (They won't.)

Comment: @Lankymart it's possible to give the same name to more than one form element, and then when submitted you can iterate over the submitted values as if it's an array. (`Request.Form(mystringvariable)` is not a plain string, you can always have `Request.Form("foo").Count` and it will work.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know, I was just trying to understand what they were doing. All I said was the key is a string, the `Request.Form` object itself is a collection. Your talking Classic ASP 101, one if the first things you learn is posting multiple values to the same `Request.Form(...)` object.

Comment: @Lankymart I'm pretty sure the OP comes from PHP background, where the name of the form elements must have square brackets, hence their confusion, and they didn't know how to treat such collection in classic ASP. Many people don't go through any tutorials before starting to program, especially when only converting stuff around. (e.g. from PHP to ASP or vice versa)

Comment: @ShadowWizard first thing I do when trying any new language. That makes sense then, I've not really dabbled much with PHP never been a requirement.

Comment: I'm creating an audit log where forms sent from one page will be captured by another page via request.form. The audit log will capture changes from an SQL table, whose columns have been conveniently assigned into an array for me.

so for example, the columns are

variable(0)="User ID"
variable(1)="Password"

I wanted to do this



Insert into tbl_name (CHANGE_ID, CHANGES_MADE) values (

Comment: I'm creating an audit log. The log should be able to handle many columns and many changes stored in an array.

so for example, the columns are

variable(0)="User ID"
variable(1)="Password"

I wanted to do this

For each x in variable

Insert into tbl_name (CHANGE_ID, CHANGES_MADE) values ('USERID', x & " changed to " & Request.form ( x  & "[]")(i) & " ' )"

Next

Final result should look like
Insert into tbl_name (CHANGE_ID, CHANGES_MADE) values ('USERID', 'Password changed to newpassword')

@ShadowWizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request.Form("matrix[]")` is taking a string value of `"matrix[]"` not an array of strings called `"matrix"`.

So you need to do either

```
a = "matrix[]"
Request.Form(a)(i)
```

or

```
a = "matrix"
Request.Form(a & "[]")(i)
```

Comment: Hi bro both your reply and @lankymart's helped me solved my issue. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @YoongTat could you post your solution as an answer so we know what you did to fix the problem?, as I'm still unclear as to what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike PHP which requires adding square brackets, in classic ASP you just have to give the same name to the elements you want to be combined into an array.

The HTML should be:

```
<input type="text" name="matrix" />
<input type="text" name="matrix" />
<input type="text" name="matrix" />
```

Then you can iterate over the submitted values like this:

```
For x=1 To Request.Form("matrix").Count
    Response.Write("Value of matrix #" & CStr(x) & "is: " & Request.Form("matrix").Item(x))
Next
```

Note that all elements are included, even if user left them empty.